# How can I determine when Wordpress is down and redirect to another site

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I've been reading Stackoverflow for many years but this is the first time I ask a question.

I want to determine when a Wordpress site (www.first-domain.ro) is down (by Wordpress itself or Wordpress plugin problem) and then to redirect the user to a new site (www.second-domain.ro). I whant this to happen only is a problem with the site, otherwise user should stay on first site.

By "down" I mean that the site is not working because wordpress or a plugin generates an error preventing wordpress to load properly.

I have been reading on google and find nothing. Also on stackoverflow I find this [Redirect to another site page if site one is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903715/redirect-to-another-site-page-if-site-one-is-down) but I can't figure out how can be implemented on wordpress.

Thanks for you all!

Comment: What do you mean by "is down" ? edit your question to explain which problems you want to detect.

Comment: the answer you found suitable for any website or application. it's server side operations, but for get answers how to work with them you should read about it

Comment: @mmm i edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan What about situation that the server is working properly but wordpress or a plugin generates a problem preventing the site toload properly

Comment: In most case where WordPress generate an unexpected error, your system cannot detect it, because it's unexpected ! If you want to check if the website is not down, you rather need another server that read regularly the first site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pre-existing plugins that allow you to modify the error message on the [White Screen of Death](https://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors). I assume you could modify one of those plugins to redirect instead of changing the message.

Here is the [WordPress redirect function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/)...

```
wp_redirect( $url );
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks @sdexp. That's what I would need.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact steps involved, here's what I would do:

1. I assume 'down' means no database so the site cannot be used, so search the core WP files for the script that generates the error `Error Establishing A Database Connection`
2. Replace the generation of that error with `header('Location: http://yourothersite.com'):`

Comment: Thanks for answer. What about the situations that the database is accesible and ok, but wordpress or a plugin generates a problem (after an update or so) preventing the site to load properly